# How to query an object from Firebase for android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read the firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

And I am still confused, on how to properly query just 1 object from my Firebase database.

Here is the lines of code I have written.

```
private Firebase mRef;
```

And in on start:

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        //Firebase
        mRef = new Firebase("my database url");

    }
```

Then in onCreate or in onStart() I use this line:

```
Query myQuery= mRef.child("key to my DataObject");
```

But I get an error in that line, and the solution it provides me is: 
change or migrate myQuery to com.firebase.client.Firebase

I am wondering which Query am I suppose to import? I have currently imported:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
```

Also, when I query an object, does something in my database have to change in order for me to retrieve objects?

Hopefully someone can provide clear and explicit example code Or steps to show how you query an object (im assuming you can just write a for loop to get a list of objects back).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume your Firebase database has below structure:

```
{
    "users" : {...}
}
```

then, to get reference of `users`, you should code as:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReferenceUsers; = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
```

Now, If your `users` object contains a list, then you need to use `push()` method to get unique key and then set value as below:

```
String key = mDatabaseReferenceUsers.push().getKey();
mDatabaseReferenceUsers.child(key).setValue(new User("Bob", 27));
```

Comment: Then how do i set a new object to the object I just queried? Because im getting an error when i do: 
`Myobject newObject = (Myobject) mDatabaseReferenceTodo;`

Comment: What datatype is mDatabaseRefereceTodo?

Comment: @Dr.Android Sorry by mistake. You can check now.

Comment: where do you declare mDatabaseRefereceTodo?

Comment: I'm getting an error on the line `DatabaseReference mData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cards");` that states:

`FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. `